# Decision Paralysis

Tags: strategy, game, pencil-and-paper-games, tic-tac-toe

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7352/48337) and is based on https://xkcd.com/1801/.</sub>

---

> Protip: If you ever need to defeat me, just give me two very similar options and unlimited internet access.

Two people are playing tic-tac-toe, and it is common knowledge that both players are susceptible to a peculiar form of decision paralysis.

At the start of a player's turn, if they can play exactly two "normally" winning moves, then that player becomes unable to make any move and immediately loses the game.

A "normally" winning move is one that would lead to a win if the remainder of the game were played perfectly between two "normal" players not susceptible to decision paralysis.

---

For example, if it is X's turn in the following position, there are exactly two normally winning moves, marked with asterisks.

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | O | X |
| O | * |  |
|  |  | * |

Overcome with decision paralysis, X immediately declares, "I lost the game," and O wins.

---

With both players knowing that they can win by either scoring three-in-a-row or paralyzing their opponent, **which player has a winning strategy**?

<sub>Disclaimer: The creator of this puzzle is not liable for any harm caused while playing decision paralysis tic-tac-toe. Please play responsibly.</sub>

Comment: 1801 eh? Too bad there's no 832 for that one...

Answer (score 5):

The one with the winning strategy is quite surprisingly

> X

First, let us note that

> if X starts anywhere else than the center, O wins on their first move like this
>
> ```
>  |X   *|     |* X  |
>  |     |     |O *  |
>  |*   O|     |     |
> ```

First options

> When X starts in the center, O has two options, corner, which gives X zero winning moves or middle, which gives X six winning moves
>
> ```
>  |O    |     |* O *|
>  |  X  |     |* X *|
>  |     |     |*   *|
> ```

Case 1

> If O goes for the corner, X wins like this
>
> ```
>  |O    |    |O   X|    |O X X|
>  |  X  | -> |  X  | -> |* X  |
>  |     |    |O    |    |O *  |
> ```

Case 2

> So O should go for the middle. Then, if X goes anywhere else than one of the more distant corners, O wins immediately like this
>
> ```
>  |  O  |     |X O  |     |* O  |
>  |O X  |     |* X  |     |X X O|
>  |* X *|     |*   O|     |*    |
> ```

Case 2.1

> So X will go for one of the bottom corners. Then the game will end like this
>
> ```
>  |  O  |    |  O O|    |* O O|
>  |  X  | -> |  X  | -> |  X  |
>  |     |    |X    |    |X X *|
> ```

Comment: Can you explain how X starting in an edge space is a loss for X? If your argument that O can win by playing in an adjacent edge space is valid, then O has exactly two such spaces they can play in, which would make this position a loss for O by decision paralysis.

Comment: @fljx From the rules: *A "normally" winning move is one that would lead to a win if the remainder of the game were played perfectly between two "normal" players not susceptible to decision paralysis.* 
O playing in an adjacent edge space is not a "normal" winning move but it is a winning move in that the two cells marked with an asterisk are the (only) two "normal" winning moves for X after that.

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but how do you use your notation? @user39583

Comment: X and O can both win, it depends who plays first.

Comment: @FlorianF or who plays *worst*. Thanks for the edit, looks much prettier now!

Answer (score -1):

Resolution

> O wins

Edge

> If X goes on an edge, O can go on an edge diagonal from X's edge and O wins from decision paralysis. * X _ [new line]O * _ [new line]_ _ _ [new line]The underscores are blank spaces and the asterisks are where X can go to double trap O. Since there are two ways to double trap, X loses.

Corner

> If X goes in a corner, O can go in the opposite corner. Now, if X goes in any of the other 2 corners, he can double trap O next turn. X loses due to decision paralysis. X _ * [new line] _ _ _ [new line]* _ O. The underscores are blank spaces and the asterisks are where X can go to double trap O. Since there are two ways to double trap, X loses.)

Center

> If X goes in the center, O can go in any corner and win. Once O goes into the corner, X has 4 options. I am going to use the algebraic notation for this. X is in B2. O is in A1. If X goes in A2, O can go in C1. Now, if X goes in C2 or B1, X wins. Since there are two ways to win, X loses. If X goes in A3, O can go in C1. If X goes anywhere but B1, he loses. O can go in C3. If X goes in B3 or C2, he wins. Since there are two ways to win, X loses. If X goes in B3, C can go in A3. Now, if X goes in B1 or A2, he wins. Since there are two ways to win, X loses. If X goes in C3, O can go in B1. Now, if X goes anywhere but C1, he loses. Now, if O goes in A2, X can win by going in A3 or C2. Since there are two ways to win, X loses.

Comment: I wasn't totally sure how to use the commands for spoilers and graphs so if a mod could help me out, that would be gr8

Comment: In the last case there are **six** winning moves for X (any of the corners work as well) and the rules state that there have to be **exactly** two for the decision paralysis to kick in.

Comment: @user39583 thx. I patched it up

Comment: B2, A1, A3, C1 does not mean X has to go to B1. It would in a normal game, but if instead X goes to A2, O will have exactly two winning moves, B1 and C2, and will lose from decision paralysis (see the case 1 from my answer above).

I'm not sure what you meant by your question about the notation, but you can get a new line inside spoiler blocks by adding two empty spaces at the end of the row and then starting a new row. The game boards in my answer are inside pre-formatted text blocks (<pre>board</pre>).